# Spatial resolution ultrasound

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

How do you detect the spots in a vertical line (the line is made by spots), in order to compute the axial resolution in ultrasound?

For example  how would like to calculate the resolution considering the small white spots in vertical

[image: For example how would like to calculate the resolution considering the small white spots in vertical]

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [ask]. So you want to detect white spots in the provided image?

Comment: Actually not in this image, the image is matrix 530x256.

Comment: then share it so we can see the real input data also what distance you want? average, min, most probable ? If you want to obtain spatial resolution of your scanner then you need more info ... and or use calibration object so you know the distance and shape of scanned object and from that and obtained scan data compute the angular resolution which will give you spatial resolution for any distance within range ... (I assume you got phase array ultrasound system measuring time of travel)